# How to make a rounded head

Tags: 3d, asymptote

In fact, i have 2 questions:

1. how to make a rounded head;
2. how to change `arrowangle` parameter globally (10 degrees, for example).

```
import three;
size(1cm,0);
draw(O--Y,Arrow3);
```

[image]

Comment: This may help https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/FAQ/section5.html